# Why did Rails change "drive" to "drife"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just ran this..

```
rails g scaffold shared_drive drive_name:string drive_path:string security_group_read:string security_group_modify:string
```

When I open the route `localhost:3000/shared_drives/new` the header reads **New Shared Drife**

When I try to create a new object on this page, I get this error

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in SharedDrivesController#create 
param is missing or the value is empty: shared_drife
```

What is going on?!?! Why did Rails change the name of my model?

Comment: It *might* have flubbed on the singularization of "drive".

Comment: @thisguy  `pry(main)> 'drives'.singularize #=> "drive"`. You can fix it using http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveSupport/Inflector/inflections

Comment: I have little typo there.. that will be `'drives'.singularize #=> "drife"`, actually my browser auto correction made this, not me. But I didn't notice it.

Comment: So what's the solution? how do I get it to singularise correctly to "drive"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's about "Inflections". You can find more information [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html). It discussed earlier in issues of rails/rails and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4997#issuecomment-3927414) is the solution.

Comment: I can not find any words that should be singularized like that.

Comment: The line of code that causes this abomination was added 12 years ago: https://github.com/rails/rails/blame/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflections.rb#L24